# range between minimal input and maximal input in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to make function where by inputting minimal and maximal 'lasting of the movie', client gets printed out every movie whose lasting is in that range. Now, **when I input (as a minimal) two-digit number and (as a maximal) three-digit number, it always says that 'No movie was found'**, but for example, when I input (for both minimal and maximal) two-digit or three-digit number, the range works, and it prints out movies that belong in that range. I've done this:

```
list_of_movies = []
def movie_list():
    with open("film.txt","r") as f:
        all_h = ["name","genre","lasting","director","main role","country","year","description"]
        for r in f.readlines():
            dicct = {}
            bla = r.strip().split("|")
            count = 0
            for i in bla:
                dicct[all_h[count]] = i
                count += 1
            list_of_movies.append(dicct)
movie_list()
def lasting():
    x=False
    lasting_min = input("Input minimal lasting: ")
    lasting_max = input("Input maximal lasting: ")
    for r in list_of_movies:
        if r["lasting"] >= lasting_min and r["lasting"] <= lasting_max:
            print()
            print("Name of the movie: ", r["name"])
            print("Genre: ", r["genre"])
            print("Lasting: ",r["lasting"],"minutes")
            print("Director: ",r["director"])
            print("Main roles: ",r["main role"])
            print("Country: ",r["country"])
            print("Year: ",r["year"])
            print("-------------------------------")
            x=True
    if x==True:
        print()
    else:
        print()
        print("No movie was found. ")
        print()
lasting()
```

And btw, I made dicts and lists so I dont have to open the txt file everytime I need something from it.

Comment: Your inputs are strings, not numbers. How do you store the movie length in your dictionary? If they are also strings, then your comparison is wrong, because they are compared lexicographically. `'201' < '7'` evaluates as True.

Comment: This might help with your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response